# Import const into another file.js

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have found online the following code to implement a SearchBar, and I saved it in searchBar.js. I would like to "import" this bar in a new file Home.js , how can I do it?

searchBar.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('');

  const onChangeSearch = query => setSearchQuery(query);

  return (
    <Searchbar
      placeholder="Search"
      onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
      value={searchQuery}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Home.js:

```
import { MyComponent } from './path/to/searchBar.js';
```

You can use it inside your component like so:

```
import { MyComponent } from './path/to/searchBar.js';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

import { MyComponent } from 'pathname'

you can also do default export

export default MyComponent in the last line of searchBar.js

then you can import like

import SearchBar from 'pathname'

you can use any name without curly braces